# JSON to HTML table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `XML` which I converted to `JSON` to get HTML table out of it.

Find the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1uh581v/)

I'm able to get the `table`, but I need width according to `_cellwidth`. I used `ng-style` but it's not working.

Also, I need to `rowspan` the blank cell with their `_realIndex` which is essentially column number to be spanned with and remove those blank later.

desired output [image: Final Table]

Please note, I wanted it to be dynamic (not hard coded).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your `ng-style` issue, change your line from

```
 ng-style="{ width: y._cellWidth }"
```

to:

```
 ng-style="{ width: (y._cellWidth + 'px') }"
```

Since your `_cellWidth` is just the number (in string format).

Comment: I see your values of `_cellWidth`. It's very higher for a normal screen so it's not getting adjusted probably for your screen width.

Comment: how can i add all cell width of first row so we can divide individual with Sum and get specify width in %